# p:selectOneButton tabindex not working in primefaces 5.0

Tags: primefaces, tabindex

I am using Primefaces 5.0. 
p:selectOneButton element is completely skipped when i tab around in the page. The code snippet is below.

Can somebody give a hack to get the tabindex work with p:selectOneButton?

```
<p:selectOneButton tabindex="50" id="orderAction" value="#{orderController.side}" onchange="toggleBuySell();">
    <f:selectItems value="#{orderDataContainer.actionTypes}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" update=" messages" process="@this " listener="#{orderController.validateAction}" oncomplete="someAction();"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
```

Comment: tabindex is _not_ an attribute for p:selectOneButton. You can try using pass through attribute: `<p:selectOneButton pt:tabindex="50" >`

Comment: @zim: that might work, but do you get access to **each** button in the select then?

Comment: @Kukeltje: I don't think so... In order to get access to each button, it might be necessary to do something like :
`<ui:repeat value="#{orderDataContainer.actionTypes}" var="type" varStatus="status">
<f:selectItem value="#{type}" p:tabindex="#{50 + status.index}"/>
</ui:repeat>`
(this is untested !)

Answer (score 0):

What I suggested in my comment doesn't work, the passtrough attribute isn't added to the input elements.
However, you can manage to do it using some jQuery:

set a widgetVar to your selectOneButton
iterate over its inputs to:
remove their hidden property (otherwise they won't be tabbable)
move them out of screen
bind focus and blur events to highlight the corresponding button (which are divs)

```
<p:selectOneButton widgetVar="orderActionWidget" id="orderAction" value="#{orderController.side}" onchange="toggleBuySell();">
    <f:selectItems value="#{orderDataContainer.actionTypes}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" update=" messages" process="@this " listener="#{orderController.validateAction}" oncomplete="someAction();"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
```

---

```
PF('orderActionWidget').buttons.find('input').each(function(index, value) {
    $(value)
    .attr('tabindex', 50 + index)
    .removeClass('ui-helper-hidden')
    .css('position', 'absolute')
    .css('left', '-1000px')
    .bind({
    focus : function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('ui-state-hover');
    },
    blur : function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: this selects the first button but on tab out control does not move to next button(select item) but moves out to other element.

Comment: Tested just now on Primefaces showcase and it does work as expected. You might check your tabindex values... If you have several selectOneButton to apply this to, use a global counter instead of `.attr('tabindex', 50 + index)`

Comment: It Works but only partially. As this only brings focus on the first button, on tab out after first button, the other buttons are skipped (eventhough I can see the tabindex set by your query.) On Shift Tab the focus comes to the last button. Further shift tab skips the other buttons. Not sure how to resolve this

Comment: I think you might want to check if there are multiple elements with the same tabindex. You can list them all using:
`$('*[tabindex]').each(function(){console.log(this)})`